# How to change Codeigniter Default pagination url style

Tags: php, pagination, codeigniter-3

By default codeigniter create pagination url something like this

http://my-url.com/index.php//controller/method/2

I want to change this to

http://my-url.com/index.php/controller/method?page=2

How to do this?

I have done these changes which is not working

```
$config = [
            'base_url' => base_url($baseUrl).'?page'.,
            'per_page' => $dataPerPage,
            'total_rows' => $totalRows,
        ];
```

But it generate url like this
http://my-url.com/index.php/controller/method?page=2/2